# How to properly dispatch app wide data from a simple class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Ideally I need a plain JavaScript class I can write to dispatch data using Redux to the rest of my app.

However, I did not know how to give a plain JavaScript class access to Redux so I wrote a dummy React component to to do this as seen below:

It renders nothing but the format gives me access to dispatch so I can dispatch data to the store.

How can I write this using a simple class without extending React?

```
import React        from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Data extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getUser();
    this.getItems();
  }

  getUser () {    
     // get data and dispatch
  }

  getItems () {
     // this.props.dispatch( // some data );
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div></div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => { return {} }
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The React-Redux `connect` function *only* works on React components.

If you need to interact with the Redux store in plain JS code, you need to either import the store directly into that file, or you need to call that code from a React component and pass through data you got from `connect`.